# basic jaydata initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, jaydata

i have a basic problem with jaydata. My Code:

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

```
  $data.Entity.extend("Todo", {

     Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
     Task: { type: String, required: true, maxLength: 200 },
     DueDate: { type: Date },
     Completed: { type: Boolean }
  });

  $data.EntityContext.extend("TodoDatabase", {

     Todos: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: Todo }
  });

  var todoDB = new TodoDatabase({
     provider: 'indexedDb', databaseName: 'MyTodoDatabase'
  });

  todoDB.onReady(function() {
     //Work with todoDB now
  });
```

});

Of couse i get an Error because the variable **Todo** in Line:

Todos: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: **Todo** }

is undefined. When I replace **Todo** with a string for example then 
**TodoDatabase** in line:

```
  var todoDB = new TodoDatabase ({
     provider: 'indexedDb', databaseName: 'MyTodoDatabase'
  });
```

in not defined / no constructor. So i do not understand 
the differenz of "Todo" and Todo nor differenz between "TodoDatabase" and
TodoDatabase. Please help i have no idea how to use this system correct.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

JayData 1.4.x+ versions are optimized to use less global objects. There are two options to make the example work with these new JayData versions:

**Option 1:** Define your entity using a variable:

```js
var Todo = $data.Entity.extend("Todo", {
 Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
 Task: { type: String, required: true, maxLength: 200 },
 DueDate: { type: Date },
 Completed: { type: Boolean }
});
```

Option 2: use compatibility script
You can use [this script](https://github.com/jaystack/jaydata/blob/development/jaydata-compatibility.js) to use entity definitions through global variables

Comment: BTW the official docs will be updated with the next official release